# upgrading javascript that adds a link to a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dynamics-crm

**I am trying to change the Sales Stage field label to a hyperlink to pop up a new browser window.**

Currently I have a form with a Sales Stage field that has a drop down::

[image]

The underlying HTML:

```
<td title="Select the sales process stage for the opportunity to indicate the probability of closing the opportunity." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="salesstagecode_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">Sales Stage</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
</div></span></td>
```

or perhaps better formatted:

[image]

---

The function that I used previously worked on an older version of the form:

```
function csjs_AddHyperlinkToLabel(sFieldId, sURL, sWindowOptions) {
    var sCurrentLabel = $("label[for='" + sFieldId + "']").html();
    $("label[for='" + sFieldId + "']").html("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('" + sURL + "', null, '" + sWindowOptions + "'); return false;\" style=\"cursor:hand; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;\">" + sCurrentLabel + "</a>");
}
```

the function above worked on a form with the following html::

[image]

**What changes would be required to the javascript to change the Sales Stage field label to a hyperlink to pop up a new browser window?**

Though I'd be very grateful for a solution, I'm looking for guidance on how to accomplish this. Thank you for your attention and time.

Unfortunately, the solutions below did not work. I ran this through the debugger and here's what I got http://screencast.com/t/fT6tHvXZzvc

The issue here is that we are passing “salesstagecode” to this function:

```
csjs_AddHyperlinkToLabel("salesstagecode", sPageURL, sWindowFeatures);
```

and this turns out to be NULL:

```
var sCurrentLabel = $("label[for='" + sFieldId + "']").html();
```

*

> The issue is that Microsoft changed the way the forms are rendered and
>   the HTML of the rendered page will no longer work with the way the
>   function was written.  The label is now in a span tag instead of a
>   label tag.  I don't know if there is a way to identify that span and
>   change the contents to have new HTML to make the text link.

*

*How do you update a span tag?*

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `target="_blank"` attribute in your hyperlink markup.

Comment: thank you very much, could you explain why this works. testing right now!

Comment: `target` attribute can take many values one of which is "_blank". It is part of HTML specifications. Check the bottom section of this resource for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: I ran this through the debugger and here's what I got http://screencast.com/t/fT6tHvXZzvc

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

change

```
 .... onclick=\"window.open('" + sURL + "', null, '" ....
```

to

```
 .... onclick=\"window.open('" + sURL + "', '_blank', '"  ....
```

Comment: thank you very much, could you explain why this works. testing right now!

Comment: 2nd argument to window.open is the name of the browser window. Leaving that null means: no new window. Setting it to the name `"_blank"` opens a new unnamed window per definition. See docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Comment: I ran this through the debugger and here's what I got http://screencast.com/t/fT6tHvXZzvc